# React-Redux reducer method errors out when executed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a first React-Redux app. I have the following container:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Visualization from '../components/visualization'

// http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components
const mapStateToProps = (state) => state;  // identity transform, for now...

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        stepForward: () => dispatch('STEP_FORWARD')
    };
}

const VisualizationContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Visualization);

export default VisualizationContainer;
```

And the following subsequent component:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Visualization extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.stepForward());
        return <div>"HELLO WORLD"</div>;
    }
}
```

However, when I run this application I error out with:

```
Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

The problem, marked with `XXX`, is that `stepForward` exists, but explodes when executed. What is the error here?

Comment: it should be `dispatch({type:'STEP_FORWARD'})`

Comment: That does it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is just as the error says. An action should be an object and no other type. You're trying to dispatch a string as an action, which is invalid. Instead, you should use an object with a `type` property set to the action's type string.

Change your `mapDispatchToProps` function to:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        stepForward: () => dispatch({
          type: 'STEP_FORWARD' 
        })
    };
}
```

and it should work.

You should actually go a bit further than that and make all your actions follow a standardized template. A nice one a lot of React devs follow is [flux-standard-action](https://github.com/acdlite/flux-standard-action).